# How to fill a ListBox in casade with comboBox (KENDO, JSP AND Servlets)

Tags: jquery, jsp, servlets, kendo-ui

I am using Kendo and I ant that the ListBox will be fill in runtime when a select one element from the ComboBox How can I do that?

```
    $("#cmbMarca").kendoComboBox({
        placeholder:"Ingrese Marca ...",
        dataTextField: "nombre",
        dataValueField: "cod_marca_aplicacion",            
        minLength: 0,
        filter: "contains",
        dataSource: srcMarcas,

    });

     $("#lstMarcas").kendoListBox({
         dropSources: ["cmbModelo"]
     });
```

Comment: Take a look at Telerik's [Cascading DropDownList](https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dropdownlist/cascadingdropdownlist) documentation.

Comment: Appers for Dropdown to dropdown I want Dropdown to listBox